# Prefetching a page into RAM

Tags: c, memory, prefetch

I'm writing a highly optimised AVL tree and now it happened that I decided to take care of the multiple page faults I have been getting during insertions. Turned out that I'm simply trying to access another page which generates a page fault. I tried using gcc's built-in prefetching functions in multiple combinations in various places across the inserting code, but no luck getting rid of them. I also tried experimenting a little bit by doing `*ptr = *ptr` to see if it would have any effect (`ptr` being the pointer I want to access which generates a page fault every once a while).
More background: I am using `malloc` to get memory for the AVL tree and then "going forward" in the memory (as in "every new insertion adds a new node in linear order"). It is thus natural that every x insertions I am trying to access a new page and thus generating a page fault. I tried prefetching the pointer itself and a pointer a few bytes after the pointer (to make sure it's on the new page), I tried aligning the prefetched pointer to 64 bytes. Maybe the built-in prefetching instructions only work for cache and don't actually load pages, I don't know.
The goal is to get that page into memory before accessing it so that I don't get page faults and get slowed down (doing millions of insertions per a test so every once a while actually becomes pretty often and big numbers emerge).
GCC 9.2.0 target mingw32, Windows 10 64bit
Code:

```c
struct net_avl_node {
  int sfd;
  int balance;
  void (*value)(int);
  struct net_avl_node* restrict parent;
  struct net_avl_node* restrict left;
  struct net_avl_node* restrict right;
};

struct net_avl_tree {
  struct net_avl_node** parts;
  struct net_avl_node* restrict head;
  struct net_avl_node* last;
  uint32_t count;
  uint32_t amount;
  uint32_t max_items_per_part;
};

int net_avl_insert(struct net_avl_tree* const tree, const int sfd, void (*callback)(int)) {
  void* restrict ptr;
  struct net_avl_node* restrict node = tree->head;
  struct net_avl_node* restrict temp;
  if(tree->amount == 0) { // first object becomes the head
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct net_avl_node*));
    if(ptr == NULL) {
      return ENOMEM;
    }
    tree->parts = ptr;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct net_avl_node) * tree->max_items_per_part);
    if(ptr == NULL) {
      free(tree->parts);
      return ENOMEM;
    }
    //memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(struct net_avl_node) * tree->max_items_per_part);
    // didn't change anything
    tree->parts[0] = ptr;
    tree->parts[0][0] = (struct net_avl_node) {
      .sfd = sfd,
      .balance = 0,
      .value = callback,
      .parent = NULL,
      .left = NULL,
      .right = NULL
    };
    tree->count = 1;
    tree->amount = 1;
    tree->head = tree->parts[0];
    tree->last = tree->parts[0];
    return 0;
  } else if(tree->count % tree->max_items_per_part == 0) { // make more space if lacking memory
    /* ... */
  }
  /*
  grab the next node (no gaps between them so going
  from the lowest address to the highest linearly,
  thus going to a new page once a while)
  */
  temp = ++tree->last;
  ++tree->count;
  while(1) {
    if(sfd > node->sfd) {
      if(node->right != NULL) {
        node = node->right;
      } else {
        *temp = (struct net_avl_node) { // a page fault
          .sfd = sfd,
          .balance = 0,
          .value = callback,
          .parent = node,
          .left = NULL,
          .right = NULL
        };
        node->right = temp;
        /* ... */
        break;
      }
    } else {
      if(node->left != NULL) {
        node = node->left;
      } else {
        *temp = (struct net_avl_node) { // a page fault
          .sfd = sfd,
          .balance = 0,
          .value = callback,
          .parent = node,
          .left = NULL,
          .right = NULL
        };
        node->left = temp;
        /* ... */
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  /* rebalancing */
  return 0;
}
```

I am also using `-O3 -Wall -lpsapi -Wno-missing-braces -Wmissing-field-initializers -D_GNU_SOURCE` flags.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post your [representative] code in a code block here. There are a number of mitigation techniques but we'd need some context to apply them. How are you _measuring_ page faults and locality? I assume you're creating the tree _once_ [more or less] and doing lots of _searching_ [because you're using an AVL tree]. If you're doing a lot of dynamic add/delete, I think you want an RB tree instead.

Comment: If you don realloc (and thus change the size) you could do a `memset(ptr, 0, size);`. This should trigger a page write and force the system to give you the page. Might still be paged out though.

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm using windows API to print process' memory usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/collecting-memory-usage-information-for-a-process and yes I am creating the tree once

Comment: One way is to _not_ `malloc(sizeof(struct mynode))` for a _single_ node. But, rather, allocate a block of nodes (e.g.) `pool = malloc(sizeof(struct mynode) * 1000000)`. Then, traverse this and create a linked list of free nodes. Then, allocate/free from/to the list. Again, in order to apply this effectively, we need the context.

Comment: @CraigEstey I edited the question, now it includes the code sample. Please let me know if you need more besides what I included. I removed some irrevelant parts.

Comment: You already have a version of the pool allocation strategy I mentioned. The [missing] code for `// make more space if lacking memory` might be helpful.

Comment: _Side note:_ You're replicating code [in three places] using _initializer_ syntax [vs assignment]. I've not seen that too often (e.g.) `*temp = (struct net_avl_node) { .sfd = sfd, .balance = 0, ...};` The cast is unnecessary. What I'm used to is: `temp->sfd = sfd; temp->balance = 0; ...`. This is just is fast and more canonical. Since I've [personally] never used an initializer in this way, I can't vouch for its speed.

Comment: There's no way to avoid page faults on the initial mapping of a page - the virtual to physical mapping doesn't exist until the first time you touch a page.  If those are the page faults you are seeing, there's no such thing as "prefetching" a page that hasn't actually been mapped yet. Since this is on insertion into your list using what appears to be newly-`malloc()` memory, I suspect that's what's happening.  But if the page faults are caused by pages that were already mapped being swapped out that you need to swap back in, then your best bet is to simply buy more RAM.

Comment: Well regarding that @AndrewHenle, I did test what Devolus suggested to map the pages, yet I still kept getting the page faults for some reason. I have plenty of memory on my system - 16GB, most of which unused at the time of testing. Seems pretty strange.

Comment: @FranciszekBalcerak What optimization level?  A compiler can optimize out `memset()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Included at the end of the post. O3.